# Creating an tree graph from a collection of objects where only parent node is known

Tags: .net, algorithm

We have a large collection of objects that we need to create a tree structure from. However, our problem is that we only know each objects parent...which makes it a bit tricky since this needs to be fast.

What is the best algorithm for creating an tree graph from a collection of objects where only parent node is known?

Comment: If each object knows its parent, you already have a tree. But the links point toward the root, instead of the more conventional kind of tree where they point the opposite direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each object create a collection of children. Run through all objects and add each object to its parent's collection.
To create a tree from all objects, you have to look at each object at least once.
From the question it seems, there is a fast way to go from an object to its parent.
So this seems to be as fast as it can get:

```
List millionsOfObjects = new List<SomeObject>(); 
FillMillonsOfObject(); 
foreach(SomeObject someObject in millionsOfObjects) 
{ 
    SomeObject parent = someObject.GetParent(); 
    parent.Children.Add(someObject);
}
```

Comment: So sort of like this? 

List<someobject> millionsOfObjects = List<someobject>();
FillMillonsOfObject();

for(int i = 0 i< millionsOfObjects.Count; i++)
{

string parentId = millionsOfObjects[i].ParentId; 
someobject parent = millionsOfObjects.Find(parentId);

parent.Children.Add(millionsOfObjects[i]);

} 

the proses needs to be fast and efficient... not sure if this is what we're looking for.

Comment: Yes, this is, what I'm proposing. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be easier? You don't have to replicate the objects, do you?

```
List millionsOfObjects = new List&ltSomeObject>(); 
FillMillonsOfObject(); 
foreach(SomeObject someObject in millionsOfObjects) 
{ 
  someObject.GetParent().children.add(someobject)
}
```